# MyEclipse connect to Tomcat server (not local)

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat, tomcat7, myeclipse

I installed MyEclipse 10 in C: Drive.
And Tomcat in F:, which is not local, mapped to (Let's just say) \OtherComp\

What do I have to do differently in order to connect to \OtherComp\ server through MyEclipse 10?

I set up the

```
Tomcat home directory: F:\Tomcat
Tomcat base directory: F:\Tomcat
```

Tomcat in \OtherComp server is working perfectly fine.
I have been using text Editor to create/modify the code.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this tutorial on the MyEclipse Website:

http://www.myeclipseide.com/documentation/quickstarts/remotedebugging

It covers remote deployment and remote debugging.

If you need more help, I suggest posting on the MyEclipse forums for better support:

http://www.myeclipseide.com/forums